# error with animation of a string - matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, animation

I am trying to get an `animation` working in `matplotlib`. I had this `code` working before but now I'm returning an error. I'm unsure if an update has caused this or not?

The `code` is below. This was working before. but now it returns an error:

```
    raise TypeError("invalid type comparison")

TypeError: invalid type comparison
```

Example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

d = ({
    'Time' : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],                                     
     })

df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (10,6))

#Event Table
Events_table = plt.table(cellText= [[''],[''],[''],[''],['']],
    colWidths = [1],
    rowLabels=['Time','1','2','3','4'],
    colLabels=['Events'],
    bbox = [0.124, 0.75, 0.236, 0.22])

Frame_number = df['Time']

label = plt.text(-180, 50, Frame_number, fontsize = 8, ha = 'center')

def animate(i) :
    label.set_text(Frame_number[i+1])

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, np.arange(0,10),# init_func = init,
                          interval = 100, blit = False)

plt.draw()
```

Comment: Try `label = plt.text(-180, 50, str(Frame_number[0]), fontsize = 8, ha = 'center')` and `label.set_text(str(Frame_number[i+1]))`.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas Kuhn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt this code would have ever worked in previous versions; in any case there are thwo problems:

- I think you will want to set your label to the *first* element of the series before the animation starts.

  ```
  label = plt.text(0, 0, Frame_number[0])
  ```
- If you use `i+1` to index the series, your animation needs to stop one index before the last one,

  ```
  ani = animation.FuncAnimation(..., frames=np.arange(0, len(Frame_number)-1) )
  ```

Complete code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data = { 'Time' : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],  })

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (10,6))

Frame_number = df['Time']

label = plt.text(0, 0, Frame_number[0])

def animate(i) :
    label.set_text(Frame_number[i+1])

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, np.arange(0,len(Frame_number)-1),
                          interval = 100, blit = False)

plt.show()
```